# Auto scroll through ag-grid unpinned rows is working but I need this plunkr to loop once it hits the bottom

Tags: ag-grid, autoscroll

I have this plunkr I have been messing with that is basically a test of my first use of ag-grid. I started off wanting the following:

Use ag-grid for the first time - done

Sort Array of data based on count, then name - done

Pin Top 5 Results at the Top - done

Auto Scroll slowly (controllable) through bottom "unpinned" results - kind of done (works in edit mode of plunkr but in just the url view mode it just jumps to the bottom... see below for workaround)

Loop back to the top SMOOTHLY once it hits the bottom where it has the appearance of just flowing like a wheel turns - this is where I am lost.

So my problem is, I dont know how to tell it has hit the bottom of the scrollable area and be able to flow the UI to give the appearance **as much as possible** that it didnt skip a beat and just restarted scrolling from the top in an endless loop. Here is my plunkr https://next.plnkr.co/plunk/J2s7Aeyp2Yr3BefC

Really as long as the "animation" looks nice and smooth I can probably live with it, Im just looking for any help.

WORKAROUND: To see the scroll work if it just jumped to the bottom, hit the red minus button a few times and it will scroll up at that rate, then once at the top just hit the blue plus a few times to make it a positive number and it should scroll smoothly to the bottom.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you can look at my plunkr for the working model of looping through the scroll.